# How to check if WebRTC uses a relay server?

Tags: webrtc

I read that WebRTC uses relay servers, if the direct peer connection doesn't work because of firewalls.

**Is there a way to check, if this is the case?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you establishing WebRTC connection, you set STUN and/or TURN for a web browser to use. If you informed a web browser with the both options, web browser will start trying to use STUN first. Then, in case of unsuccess it will try to use TURN.

The 'relay server' is a TURN-server.

As I know, there is no standard way to know out which option a web browser decided to use: STUN or TURN.

In other hand, if you're the owner of TURN server, you can see whether web client does use it or not, and then send this information to the client.

**UPDATED**

This is my code: https://github.com/fycth/webrtcexample/blob/master/www/js/rtc_lib.js

You can see there I use just STUN server, so it is p2p or nothing, and no relay.

Comment: Ah, so I just have to leave the TURN server and no relay server will be used and I only get real p2p or nothing?

Comment: Yes, you can pass to RTCPeerConnection just STUN server (without TURN). In that case it will try to use p2p without relays.

Comment: Setting only a TURN server does not necessarily mean that TURN will be used and the media will be relayed, as most TURN servers implementations will also provide stun candidates to the application. To force the application to use relay, you need filter the list of candidates from the SDP and let only the relay ones.

Comment: I want the opposite. p2p or nothing.

Comment: Can we find out stun or turn in the chrome://webrtc-internals/ ?

Comment: @Robert if you examine an SDP, you will see the candidates list that a peer can handle in the offer. You have host, srflx (STUN) or relay (TURN). Check which one is being used by your peers!

Comment: @igracia Thanks! I tried apprtc source code from github & found peers exchanging candidates in the console. Do you which candidate pair is chosen to be the final candidate pair? Here's my log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/46nveiwiyah8n38/webrtc_log.html?dl=0

Comment: @Robert You could check the 'googRemoteAddress' or the 'googRemoteCandidateType', and see what kind of candidate was chosen.

Comment: @fycth If TURN is hosted on my server, how can I tell the client that which one is used STUN or TURN ? Can you please tell more on this

Answer (score 4):

In chrome. go to chrome://webrtc-internals, go to  succeeded connection-googCandidate pair(in black letters) check if googLocalcandidatetype is relay, then webrtc uses relay connection . If googLocalcandidatetype is local, then it uses peer to peer connection
In firefox, go to about:webrtc, if the succeeded connection contains any candidate as relayed-udp, then webrtc uses relay connection